# How to convert matrix to structure with following output

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell

How to convert matrix A into structure B with field x, so that following output can be obtained.

```
    A=[2 3 4; 5 1 8; 4 4 6; 7 3 9] %input matrix

%desired output
B(1).x=[2,3,4]
B(2).x=[5,1,8]
B(3).x=[4,4,6]
B(4).x=[7,3,9]
```

A is actually large matrix and I want to avoid "for" loop.

Comment: There is nothing in matlab (or possibly any other programming language) corresponding to your desired output. Are there too many parantethises?

Comment: Did you mean `[[2,3,4];[5,1,8];[4,4,6];[7,3,9]]` ?

Comment: B.x(1)=[2,3,4]
B.x(2)=[5,1,8]
B.x(3)=[4 4 6]
B.x(4)=[7 3 9]

Comment: `B.x(1)` refers by definition to a single array element. Do you mean `B(1).x` or `B.x{1}`?

Comment: @Will
It is B(1).x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First use [`num2cell`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2cell.html) to convert `A` to a cell array where each cell contains one row of `A`. Then use [`cell2struct`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2struct.html) to obtain your result.

```
Bcell = num2cell(A, 2);  %
B = cell2struct(Bcell, 'x', size(A,2));
```

<sup><sub>% Thanks to [Will](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1306647/will) for suggesting num2cell in place of mat2cell.</sub></sup>